# Launching Anaconda Prompt from VBA (Or Command Line)

Tags: python, python-3.x, vba, powershell, anaconda

So far I was being able to launch my python scripts using Excel VBA by doing something like this:

```
Sub ratesmarkup()
Ratespath = "python " & """Drive:\Lambda\Lambda\Lambda\Lambda\Python \Python Code.py"""
Cmd_Line = Shell("cmd.exe /S /K" & Ratespath & "&" & "exit", vbHide)
End Sub
```

Which was working perfectly fine until now. I started testing using Anaconda for a new script and my new script uses the pyxlsb module that I imported via Anaconda as I couldn't use that module with regular PyCharm. Long story short, I want to know how could I modify this script to launch the Anaconda prompt instead of the regular cmd.exe Command Line.

When I launch this into the Anaconda Prompt it works:

```
python "Drive:\Lambda\Lambda\Lambda\Lambda\Python \Python Code.py"
```

But when I try launching it from regular Command Line it gives me this error in the terminal:

```
"ValueError: Unknown engine: pyxlsb"
```

Yet when I try to install the said pyxlsb module (although I already have it to my knowledge), it says:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyxlsb in c:\python\python-3.5.1\lib\site-packages (1.0.6)
```

The python on Anaconda is 3.7 while the regular one is 3.5. I am using the pyxlsb engine in this manner:

```
 pandas.read_excel(engine = "pyxlsb")
```

Which if I understood requires a certain version of Python, that is provided to me through Anaconda. This is at work so I can't just install a different version of standalone Python just like that. So basically is there any possible way of being able to launch the anaconda based python script through VBA by modifying my currently already existing sub? Can't find nothing that answers this directly.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start virtual environment first.second step is run your script inside the virtual environment.create a batch file including all the steps you need to execute and execute batch file through your VB script.
lets say your windows user is `TMF` and your virtual environment is `myenv`.

batch file

```
@echo on
set root=C:\Users\TMF\Anaconda3
call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root%
call activate myenv
"C:\Users\TMF\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\python.exe" "S:\Market Risk\Middle Office\Corporate Treasury\Politique Investissement\Python\PCBONDS.py"
pause
```

Comment: I am rather novice to Python but isn't it late to create the virtual environment since my script is already done? Isn't that something I would have needed to do prior to actually writing it? I've never used virtual environment, I will look into how to set up one. Thanks.

Comment: Your script is nothing to do with virtual environment..all you have to do 1) create virtual environment 2) install your required packages inside the environment 3)activate the environment 4) run your python script through environment.step 3 and step 4 is automated by the batch script i mentioned in the answer. now you need to create a environment and install your packages inside the env using pip or conda commands https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

Comment: hello just tried it. I did create the virtual environment under a path on my drive but your lines of code doesn't seem to be valid VBA code according the Excel... The @echo line for start doesn't work in VBA and the call commands are all redded out. or am i forgetting something?

Comment: these codes are not vb codes.It is a batch script.you should create a batch file including these commands with relevent env name and file paths and execute batch file through VB script.

Comment: you need to activate virtualenvironment, so `call activate <whatever your environment name> `

Comment: great.. happy coding

Comment: hey false alert. Still says No module name Pandas and I do activate the virtualenv with my line that goes like this: call activate "C:\Users\libm002\\Documents\Python Scripts" And I see the pandas folder within the Lib-sitespackages folder. what am i doing wrong? –

Comment: try to install it again.pandas should be install inside your virtualenvironment

Comment: MAN. It works! you are the MAN!!! I even figured how to launch the .bat file from VBA!

Now the finishing touch. I would like to run this script from different computers than mine (my colleagues). I believe they have Anaconda installed on their respective drive, but the current batch file and VBA code is related to my drive and the virtual environment is on my C:\ drive. I tried installing it on the S:\ drive of the job, but it said something along the lines of permissions denied or insufficient... Do you know if it can be done or I need to ask access to my job?

Comment: The issue was that I had installed python 3.5 in my virtualenv instead of python 3.7.7. When I reinstalled the virtualenv by specifying python=3.7 . I reinstalled the packages and it now worked. I now need to make it flexible so that it can run on other computers than mine by 1) Making a virtualenv and a .bat file on the public drive S:\ and 2) Modifying the .bat so that it detects the Anaconda location of the user automatically.. can it be done???

Comment: yep.you can export current environement configuration to yaml file and restore the same environment in another machine using the yml file. to export env `conda env export > environment.yml` and 
                                
to restore `conda env create --name envname --file=environment.yml`

Comment: Thanks again it works!! I couldn't use the     conda env export > env.yml as it kept saying access denied but I managed to clone the env by using      conda create -p newenv --clone oldenv .

Now, for the     root=C:\Users\TMF\Anaconda3 part. Is it possible to make it so that the TMF component is dynamic and detect the user directly within the code within having to specify it myself? Or would I have to make multiple batch file for each user. My virtuelenv and the batch file I am currently using are on the S:\ network drive, but the Anaconda is still linked to my personal drive C:\

Comment: you can pass pass variable to the batch file via vb script or whatever script you start the batch file.

Comment: And again it worked! Man I can't thank you enough!! I just learned so much handy stuff from you, you have no clue! Sir all the blessings to you and good luck for everything, I thought I would give up at first when I initially saw your first answer and didn't understand the lines of code haha. But man feels good! thanks thanks and thanks!

Comment: glad to help you,,plz accept the answer..happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

To those who like conclusions lol.

My .bat file ended up looking like this:

```
@ECHO ON
set root=C:\Users\%1%\Anaconda3
call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root%
call activate "Drive:\Lambda\Lambda\Lambda\Lambda\Python"
"Drive:\Lambda\Lambda\Lambda\Lambda\Python \Python Code.py"
PAUSE
```

Where the %1% holds the value of the variable that I will pass through my VBA script, in this case the username of the user currently using the PC.

The VBA script looks like this:

```
Sub VABONDS()
User = Environ("UserName")

batpath = "pushd " & """Drive:\Lambda\Lambda\Lambda\Lambda\Python\"""
bathfile = "PCBONDS.bat "

Set CMD = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
CMD.Run "cmd.exe /S /K" & batpath & "&" & bathfile & User & "&" & "exit", 
vbNormalFocus, True

End Sub
```

Where the User = Environ("UserName") allows me to get  the username of the user dynamically.

Just thought I would share as it could help others !!

Comment: Hey I am experiencing the same problem, actually what @Rajith Thennakoon wrote is what I guess I need to do. Steps 1, 2, 3 and so on. 

The problems I have are two: 1) In a VBA (from Excel) I need to be able to create or call the virtual environment, and 2) in the same VBA call all libraries so these are installed. Maybe this can be done with a .py file.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Hey, actually you launch the bat file from VBA, it's within the bat file that you will activate the virtual environment in which you already have installed your packages/libraries and then you will launch your py script through the virtual environment. So steps would be 1) create the bat file in which you activate the virtual environment and launch the python script, 2) launch it from VBA.

Comment: This seems very straightforward. So far, I have managed to install a new environment and all the necessary libraries from an .YML file. How can I do the bat file to activate the virtual environment and launch the python script? Any suggestions?

Comment: To create the .bat file, simply need to open Notepad, type the necessary lines into Notepad. Then when you save, do Save As,  in Save as type: "All Files" and don't forget to put the .bat extension at the end